# How to concatenate query result executed in Excel

Tags: excel, oracle

I have an Excel that collects product data from an Oracle database. This process is executed once a day and one of its columns is the execution date.

The problem is that every time I run the query data is updated. What I want is to append the result below the existing data, so I can generate graphs showing some product information through the time.

How could I do that?

Thanks is advance!

Comment: do you have a screen shot or something like a formula to show us ?

Comment: I am not using formula. It just connects to Excel, execute an SQL and retrieve the data... nothing else...

Comment: Do you know if you are using Microsoft Query to pull this external data? If so I believe you will need to copy your results to a new sheet before rerunning your query. I see several options under the External Data Properties section but they all seem to overwrite the source data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just change the date in your query to a specific date that you would like to set as the begin date for your data pool?  You would probably have to batch it occasionally as the file would probably get rather large, but just a suggestion if I'm understanding the question correctly.  Otherwise, you could take @Dank advice and just copy the data into another worksheet to create a "master file" to populate your graphs.